# Does Chronicle queue ever delete files?

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I am using Chronicle Queue 4.5.15 in one of my apps running on several Linux hosts. Each instance of the app had its own chronicle queue which usually stores several million strings.

Recently i have noticed queue files on each instance vanishing. My app does have code to delete chronicle files once the tailer cycle increments however i have logging in there to say when this happened and haven't seen this occur in the logs.

My question is - does the Chronicle library every delete queue files for any reason? I thought that the library never deleted files but i just want to confirm this so i can eliminate it from my investigation into why the files are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Chronicle library every delete queue files for any reason?

This is only done in tests as an explicit call to clean up test files. It doesn't do this automagically, nor is there a way to set it to do so without adding code to do this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!